# why did MSDN remove _In_ & co from the WinAPI documentation?

Tags: winapi, documentation, msdn

here is the old MSDN SetWindowPos documentation

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowPos(
  _In_      HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  _In_      int X,
  _In_      int Y,
  _In_      int cx,
  _In_      int cy,
  _In_      UINT uFlags
);
```

and here is the new SetWindowPos documentation:

```
BOOL SetWindowPos(
  HWND hWnd,
  HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  int  X,
  int  Y,
  int  cx,
  int  cy,
  UINT uFlags
);
```

why is _In_ / _In_opt_ / _Out_ / _Out_opt_ / _Inout_ / _Inout_opt_ removed from the MSDN documentation?

(imo they were useful, giving a quick overview of which arguments were optional, which were modified, which were only read, and which were both read and modified~)

Comment: Their new documentation looks very auto-generated and some of it not very well. E.g. all macro functions (e.g. ListView_InsertItem) are documented as `void` whether they return a value or not. What you've noticed is another example of the shoddy standards Microsoft have these days.

Comment: FWIW if you have the MSDN documentation installed locally, then the same SetWindowPos is documented in (at least) 3 places, and it (still) shows the SAL annotations under desktop app technologies / desktop app user interface / windows and messages / windows / reference / functions, but not under programming reference for windows api / security and identity / winUser.h.

Comment: I would have recommend that you directed that question to the owners of the documentation, had Microsoft not shut off any usable feedback channel for issues like this.

Comment: @hanshenrik, Thanks for sharing this. I am also trying to report this issue internally.